# High speed control loop with high resolution ADC

Tags: power-supply, adc, pid-controller

I'm designing a digital lab power supply for the sake of learning and also because I need one lol. I'm planning to use a simple 50Hz transformer with a Buck converter (I know this brings switching noise and that a linear solution would be much cleaner in terms of noise but I don't want big heatsinks) so I will be implementing a PID controller with a dsPIC sampling at about 1MSPS.

The dsPIC only has 10 bit ADC which also isn't the best ADC and I would like to have a resolution in the output voltage of 10mV or 5mV so for this I would need a higher resolution and better external ADC like a 16 or 14 bit ADC. The problem with this ADCs is that they are really slow (1 to 10KSPS) so I can't implement my control loop with this.

How is this done on commercial power supplies?

1. They use a lower resolution and faster ADC to implement the control loop to prevent over-shoot and then when the output is settled read from the high resolution ADC which is also the voltage displayed to the user?
2. They just use a low speed ADC and the over-shoot/oscillations are compensated with passive components?
3. The control loop is implemented with analog components and the ADC are only to the display the voltage to the user?
4. They use an expensive high resolution and fast ADC?

Comment: "How is this done on commercial power supplies" - They don't use ADCs - get into the real world of switch mode power supplies and the analogue world LOL. OK then, number (3) in your question is the answer having re-read the question.

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/intelligent-power/integration-levels/level-4-digital-control

Comment: "I would like to have a resolution in the output voltage of 10mV or 5mV" - why?

Comment: I think many commercial units either don't care about the price of high end ADCs (why would they? Industry has *deep* pockets). But equally likely, is that the ADCs and DACs are used only as references, while opamps take care of the high speed control. Here's a simple opamp regulator - Vref goes to your DAC while Vout goes to your load and your ADC https://i.imgur.com/3I8izRo.png

Comment: Normally, (3). But  like the idea of a digitally controlled solution. You could use a fast (but low resolution) ADC for the I and D terms, and a slow but high res one for the I term.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Because that's the target resolution I want to design the power supply to have, it's not so easy to achieve so it's a challenge :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes, that was my initial idea but I wasn't sure about how this was managed in commercial products, thank you!

Comment: @Andres Did you actually build the power supply in the end? If so, what approach did you use?

Comment: Hi @nqtronix! In the end I used the 10-bit ADC from the dsPIC for everything and settled for a lower output resolution